# Android and IOS app crashes when using googlemaps

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, ionic-framework, crash

Android and IOS app crashes when navigating to maps page. But able to see the map on ionic cordova run browser -l

cordova plugin list

```
com.razorpay.cordova 0.16.1 "RazorpayCheckout"
cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release 2.1.0 "cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release"
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 2.1.0 "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.1 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 2.4.0 "Cordova FCM Push Plugin"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.2.1 "File Opener2"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.6.3-20190614-1928 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-ionic 5.3.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.2.2 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

**If you use `@ionic-native/google-maps`, please tell the package.json (only `@ionic-native/core` and `@ionic-native/google-maps` are fine mostly)**

```
@ionic-native/core :  "^4.4.0",
@ionic-native/google-maps : "^4.14.0",
```

**Current behavior:**
- App crashed when navigating to maps page.

**Expected behavior:**
- App should show google map.

Comment: Have you add api key for google map ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add api key in your config.xml :

```
<widget ...>
  <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="(api key)" />
  <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value="(api key)" />
</widget>
```

I see u are using a unstable version, try to install  the 2.6.2 version.

Comment: Hi sam,
thanks for your suggestion.
I Already added these fields in cofig.xml.
and tried 2.6.2, but got the same.

Comment: yes, 
Here is the logcat 

```
2019-07-17 16:57:33.964 10331-10331/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.test, PID: 10331
    java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785051@17.7.85 (040408-253824076):22)
```

Comment: config.xml. 
```
<preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="AIzaSyB****************6Q-jiKe81n0" />
<preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value="AIN*****************v3n8zulvQ" />
```
package.json : 
```
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
  "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "AIz****************6",
  "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "AIS*****************v3",
  "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.0.1",
  "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+",
  "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "This.",
  "LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app ."
}